# Por qué se me cae cuando quiero pasar los datos de una orden de venta a una entrega en sap?

Tags: c#, sap

Estoy creando un botón de entrega en la orden de venta en SAP BO para enviar los datos, el problema que tengo es que falla al momento de iniciar la transacción ya que me pide el CardCode de la tabla ODLN siendo que el ejemplo que vi por internet no pide ese dato en la petición.
He ido debugeando cada paso y revisando el código, pero no encuentro como arreglar este problema ya que esto es nuevo y hay muy poca Informacion por internet a no que pague una academia.

La parte en que falla el Código es este ya que he revisado en general como poder arreglarlo y me sigue fallando

```
    oCompany.StartTransaction();
     if(oNe.Add() == 0)//En esta Parte falla la Petiticon
                {
                    SBO_Application.StatusBar.SetText("Entrega Creada: " + oCompany.GetNewObjectKey(), BoMessageTime.bmt_Medium, BoStatusBarMessageType.smt_Success);
                    oCompany.EndTransaction(BoWfTransOpt.wf_Commit);
                    cmd = "Select T0.DocNum From ODLN TO Where T0.DocEntry='" + Convert.ToString(oCompany.GetNewObjectKey()) + "'";

                    oRecord.DoQuery(cmd);

                    SBO_Application.ActivateMenuItem("2051");
                    Form form = SBO_Application.Forms.ActiveForm;
                    form.Mode = BoFormMode.fm_FIND_MODE;
                    ((EditText)form.Items.Item("8").Specific).Value = Convert.ToString(oRecord.Fields.Item("DocNum").Value);
                    form.Items.Item("1").Click(BoCellClickType.ct_Regular);
                }
                else
                {
                    SBO_Application.StatusBar.SetText("Error en la entrega: " + oCompany.GetLastErrorDescription(), BoMessageTime.bmt_Medium, BoStatusBarMessageType.smt_Error);
                    oCompany.EndTransaction(BoWfTransOpt.wf_RollBack);
                }
```

El codigo que estoy usando es el siguiente

```
    public static void SBO_Application_ItemEvent(string FormUID, ref ItemEvent pVal, 
    out bool BubbleEvent)
    {
        BubbleEvent = true;
        try
        {
          
            if (pVal.FormTypeEx == "139")
            {
                if (pVal.EventType == BoEventTypes.et_FORM_LOAD && pVal.BeforeAction == false)
                {
                    Form oForm = SBO_Application.Forms.Item(FormUID);
                    Item oItem;
                    Button oButton;
                    oItem = oForm.Items.Add("btnEntrega", BoFormItemTypes.it_BUTTON);

                    oButton = ((SAPbouiCOM.Button)(oItem.Specific));

                    oButton.Caption = "Entrega";

                    oItem.Top = oForm.Height - (oItem.Height + 48);
                    oItem.Left = (oItem.Width + 20) + 75;

                }

                if(pVal.EventType == BoEventTypes.et_CLICK && pVal.BeforeAction == true && pVal.ItemUID == "btnEntrega")
                {
                    //Entrega
                    Documents oNe = (Documents)oCompany.GetBusinessObject(BoObjectTypes.oDeliveryNotes);
                    Form oForm = SBO_Application.Forms.Item(FormUID);
                    Recordset oRecord = (Recordset)oCompany.GetBusinessObject(BoObjectTypes.BoRecordset);
                    Item oItem;
                    EditText oText;

                    oItem = oForm.Items.Item("8");
                    oText = (EditText)oItem.Specific;

                    string cmd = "Select T0.CardCode,T1.DocEntry,T1.LineNum,T1.Dscription From ORDR T0 Inner Join RDR1 T1 on T0.DocEntry=T1.DocEntry "+
                        "where T0.DocNum='"+oText.Value+"'";

                    oRecord.DoQuery(cmd);

                    if(oRecord.RecordCount > 0)
                    {
                        oNe.CardCode = (string)oRecord.Fields.Item("CardCode").Value;
                        oNe.DocType = BoDocumentTypes.dDocument_Service;
                        oNe.DocDate = DateTime.Now;
                        oNe.DocDueDate = DateTime.Now;
                        while (!oRecord.EoF)
                        {
                            oNe.Lines.BaseEntry = (int)oRecord.Fields.Item("DocEntry").Value;
                            oNe.Lines.BaseLine = (int)oRecord.Fields.Item("LineNum").Value;
                            oNe.Lines.BaseType = Convert.ToInt32(BoObjectTypes.oOrders);
                            oNe.Lines.ItemDescription = (string)oRecord.Fields.Item("Dscription").Value;
                            oNe.Lines.Add();
                            oRecord.MoveNext();
                        }
                    }

                    oCompany.StartTransaction();
                    if(oNe.Add() == 0)//En esta Parte se Cae la Petiticon
                    {
                        SBO_Application.StatusBar.SetText("Entrega Creada: " + oCompany.GetNewObjectKey(), BoMessageTime.bmt_Medium, BoStatusBarMessageType.smt_Success);
                        oCompany.EndTransaction(BoWfTransOpt.wf_Commit);
                        cmd = "Select T0.DocNum From ODLN TO Where T0.DocEntry='" + Convert.ToString(oCompany.GetNewObjectKey()) + "'";

                        oRecord.DoQuery(cmd);

                        SBO_Application.ActivateMenuItem("2051");
                        Form form = SBO_Application.Forms.ActiveForm;
                        form.Mode = BoFormMode.fm_FIND_MODE;
                        ((EditText)form.Items.Item("8").Specific).Value = Convert.ToString(oRecord.Fields.Item("DocNum").Value);
                        form.Items.Item("1").Click(BoCellClickType.ct_Regular);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        SBO_Application.StatusBar.SetText("Error en la entrega: " + oCompany.GetLastErrorDescription(), BoMessageTime.bmt_Medium, BoStatusBarMessageType.smt_Error);
                        oCompany.EndTransaction(BoWfTransOpt.wf_RollBack);
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            SBO_Application.StatusBar.SetText("Error General" + ex.ToString(), BoMessageTime.bmt_Medium, BoStatusBarMessageType.smt_Error);
            if (oCompany.InTransaction)
            {
                oCompany.EndTransaction(SAPbobsCOM.BoWfTransOpt.wf_RollBack);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "se me cae" osea.. tira un error.. de algun tipo... que obviamente ofuscate en tu try catch... por favor, busca el error original y agregalo a la pregunta para que puedan ayudarte.. se cae, no nos dice nada.. ni siquiera nos decis en que linea pasa....

Comment: si tienes razon por los modismos que cada país tiene, se me olvida usar términos comprensibles en general para la comunidad

Comment: el problema no son los modismos.. el problema, es que seguis sin especificar cual es el error...

Answer (score 0):

Según indicas lo que te devuelve `oCompany.GetLastErrorDescription()` es que falta el `CardCode`. sería bueno que pongas exactamente esa descripción y el código.

Aquí estás seteando esa propiedad

```
oNe.CardCode = (string)oRecord.Fields.Item("CardCode").Value;
```

Pero, ¿has verificado que en efecto te devuela un valor es query y sea el correcto? Debugueando puedes ver si oNe.CardCode tiene el valor que necesitas. Usualmente la mayoría los documentos de SAP B1 piden un `CardCode` ya que se los debe de asignar a un cliente o proveedor.

Puedes revisar la carpeta del SDK de SAP B1 `(C:\Program Files\SAP\SAP Business One SDK`), que usualmente viene instalado en la máquina del cliente o le puedes pedir al proveedor que te dé o instale el SDK. Allí puedes encontrar varios archivos de ayuda, uno de esos es del DI API. Allí hay ejemplos de transacciones y te indican para cada objeto qué campos son necesarios; en este caso `DeliveryNotes`.